# Python: Thread using a chunk of data

Tags: python, python-3.x, list, multithreading, chunks

I want to use a thread while writing into an output file. My problem doing this is that I can't execute multiple threads without initialising them.

For example:

```
chunk = [[1,2,3,4,5],[6,7,8,9,10]]
t1 = Thread.threading(target=func, args=(chunk[0],))
t1.start()
t2 = Thread.threading(target=func, args=(chunk[1],))
t2.start()
```

What I want to do instead is:

```
for i in range(0, len(chunk)):
    t = Thread.threading(target=func, args=(chunk[i],))
    t.start()
```

I've ran into the issue that because of the for loop the next thread is being started after the first one completed.

Is there any solution to this so I don't end up using the first method?

Thanks :)

Comment: Is the work in these threads really fast? The thread execution profile is the same in both examples. The first thread in the first example is just as likely to finish as the first thread in the second one. If you want some order to execution of the threads, you'll need some sort of control structure like an Event or Barrier object.

Comment: I thought threads are the fastest way to execute things parallel. Do you maybe have any recommendations for an article which could help me find the best control structure or can you maybe give me a code example for my code?

Comment: There's a tradeoff between threads and processes: threads can't execute in parallel if they're doing work which requires holding the GIL, and processes have the overhead of using pickle to pass objects back and forth between processes. Which one is better will depend on the problem you're solving.